# Getting more information from HttpContext.User

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there a way to get additional active directory details from `HttpContext.User`?

Currently, I can use it to get the user identity: `HttpContext.User.Identity`.

What if I needed to access more attributes, such as `employeeId`, `directReports`, etc? Can I do it the same way? If not, what's the best way to implement that for an ASP.net / MVC application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand you want to get this information from the Active Directory?
Check the following post for that: [How to get the current user's Active Directory details in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637486/how-to-get-the-current-users-active-directory-details-in-c-sharp)