# How to retrieve AD infomation with builtin Windows commands (no powershell)

Tags: windows, active-directory

I am writing a program which requires some information from the Active Directory. The data I need is the email address of the current user. Via the Sysinternals AD Explorer I was able to find the correct path to the email address, but is there a way if querying that path to get the value?
My research only turns up Cmdlets for AD, but the customer's Powershell does not have the Active Directory Module installed and I cannot add it.
Then I saw that there is the ldap protocol (ldap://). But I don't know how I can access that.
Is there a way of retrieving any given information from the AD without having to install external tools, Cmdlets etc.?
Best regards
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it from the command line, you'd need to use [`dsget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc755162(v=ws.11)) or [`dsquery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc732952(v=ws.11)), but that's still hard.

You can do it in PowerShell without installing anything. All of the .NET classes are available in PowerShell, so you can do exactly the same thing as [this C# answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61504889/1202807) I wrote a while ago. It would look something like this:

```
$sid = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().User
$user = [ADSI]"LDAP://<SID=$sid>"
$email = $user.mail
```

Then you'll have the current user's email address in `$email`.

`[ADSI]` is a [type accelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_accelerators) for [`DirectoryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry).